# React - express expected in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react functional component.
When I use map function in below code, it keeps showing error `Expression expected.`

```
return(
        <div class="sm:grid sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4 space-y-4 sm:space-y-0">
            {(news.articles).map(new => {
                return (
                    <Card
                    title={article.title}
                    content={article.content}
                    onClick={() => {
                      console.log("clciked");
                    }}
                    />
                )
            })
            } 
        </div>
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing it is the `new` you are using in the map callback being a reserved keyword in Javascript. Use another identifier, like `article` you are already referencing.

```
return(
  <div class="sm:grid sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4 space-y-4 sm:space-y-0">
    {news.articles.map(article => {
      return (
        <Card
          title={article.title}
          content={article.content}
          onClick={() => {
            console.log("clciked");
          }}
        />
      )
    })} 
  </div>
)
```

Comment: It is a reserved word in Javascript.

Comment: @madflow Oops, quite correct. ‍♂️ Thanks.

Comment: you found the soluion?